# How safe is SharePoint Online (Office 365) login?

Tags: sharepoint-online, login, oauth

I have some discussions with my work mates about how **safe** is *SharePoint Online* login. I think it is just as *DropBox*, *FaceBook* or any other application with a form. I know that *Office 365* uses *OAuth2* and that means a separation between the application and the provider and that solves one part of the problem. But, what about the client side?

Always I've been asked about this I say that having a *SharePoint* farm in *Azure VM* and connected via *VPN* is more *secure* than *SharePoint Online* (*IaaS vs SaaS*) because I understand that *SharePoint Online* is not safer.

- Could we have some leves of security?
- How can we measure that?
- How can we take a decision knowing the weak points?

Please, could you throw some light on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a home/personal Office 365 stand point, yes it would be similar to any other internet service that if your password is compromised, then someone can get into your tenant.

However, any business that is using Office 365 is highly likely to be synchronizing objects from local Active Directory to SharePoint, and therefore you are using auth credentials from your network. This is typically handled by ADFS or third party auth providers.

What that means then is that when you try to hit any of the Office 365 workloads, they see you are from a domain that uses their own authentication mechanism. When on your network, you pass through pretty seamlessly. When you are off your network, you get presented with your organization's or third party's auth screen and then get redirected to the desired workload. If you fail that auth, you don't get in.